# Google Calendar API vb .net 2010, reach the event time of a calendar event

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I am working on a custom notepad application that supports the Google Calendar API and have been on a dead end for some time now. The problem is that I try (using the standard code) to update / adjust an existing event. But in VB I only manage to get an AtomFeed and that allows everything but changing the Event date / time (as far as I could see / Google). The code:

```
EventQuery myQuery = new EventQuery(feedUrl);
myQuery.Query = "Tennis";
EventFeed myResultsFeed = myService.Query(myQuery);
if (myResultsFeed.Entries.Count > 0) {
AtomEntry firstMatchEntry = myResultsFeed.Entries0];
String myEntryTitle = firstMatchEntry.Title.Text;
```

In this code the query returns an EventFeed type that contains the start / end time of a single occuring event easy accessible through the When class. However if I translate that code to VB instead of C# (I created my notes application in VB.NET 2010) the service.Query method only returns an AtomFeed. I can not seem to acces the Event Start / End date from the AtomEntry, nor have I found a way to parse or convert the Atom type to the Event type classes... My current code:

```
Dim myResultsFeed As AtomFeed = service.Query(myQuery)
Dim firstMatchEntry As AtomEntry

If (myResultsFeed.Entries.Count > 0) Then
firstMatchEntry = myResultsFeed.Entries(0)
firstMatchEntry.Title.Text = updatedNote.Subject

'Would be available in the EventEntry class
'firstMatchEntry.times.add(New [When](gNote.GCalendarDate, endDate))
firstMatchEntry.Update()
```

I have searched the net extensively. Any responses are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question but if you want to update your start and end time from vb.net, your first have to clear the existing time and add a new time as if you would do it with create event. Following is the code.

>

> ```
>        Dim srvce As New Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService("gCal")
>        Dim query As New FeedQuery
>        Dim evntEntry As Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry
>
>        query.Uri = New Uri(eventSelfURI) 'SELF URI IS THE URI FOR GOOGLE CALENDAR FEED
>
>        srvce.setUserCredentials("<<EMAIL>>", "<<PASSWORD>>")
>        Dim calfeed As AtomFeed
>        calfeed = srvce.Query(query)
>
>
>        evntEntry.Title.Text = newTitle
>        evntEntry.Content.Content = newContent
>
>        'SETTING UP THE START AND END TIME - FIRST CLEARING EXISTING TIMING AND ADDING NEW
>        evntEntry.Times.Clear() 'THIS WILL CLEAR THE EXISTING TIME
>        Dim newTime As New [When]()
>        newTime.StartTime = newStartDateTime
>        newTime.EndTime = newEndDateTime
>        evntEntry.Times.Add(newTime)
>
>        evntEntry.Update()
> ```

Hope this will help you.